# proof : $(\forall z\in \mathbb{C}-\{2\} ) \ \ \overline{f(z)}=-f(z) \Leftrightarrow (z-1+\frac{1}{2}i)(\bar{z}-1-\frac{1}{2}i)-\frac{5}{4}=0 $

Tags: complex-analysis, geometry, complex-numbers

$$f(z)=\frac{z+i}{z-2}\ \  ; \; \; z\in\mathbb{C}-\{2\}$$
proof :
$(\forall z\in \mathbb{C}-\{2\} ) \ \ \overline{f(z)}=-f(z) \Leftrightarrow (z-1+\frac{1}{2}i)(\bar{z}-1-\frac{1}{2}i)-\frac{5}{4}=0 $
this is what I did,
$$(z-1+\frac{1}{2}i)(\bar{z}-1-\frac{1}{2}i)-\frac{5}{4}=0$$
$$z(\bar{z}-1-\frac{1}{2}i)+(-1+\frac{1}{2}i)(\bar{z}-1-\frac{1}{2}i)-\frac{5}{4}=0$$
$$z\bar{z}-(1+\frac{1}{2}i)z+(-1+\frac{1}{2}i)\bar{z}+(1+\frac{1}{2}i)(1-\frac{1}{2}i)-\frac{5}{4}=0$$
$$z\bar{z}-(1+\frac{1}{2}i)z+(-1+\frac{1}{2}i)\bar{z}=0$$
but I am not sure for what I have to do next, I want to get this result :
$$ (\bar{z}-i)(z-2)=-(z+i)(\bar{z}-2) $$
What I have to do next? if there is any other way tell me please.

Comment: Simply expand $(\bar{z}-i)(z-2)=-(z+i)(\bar{z}-2)$ and you will find the same equation as above.

Comment: You should first go from $(\overline{z}-i)(z-2)=-(z+i)(\overline{z}-2)$ to $2z\overline{z}-(2+i)z+(-2+i)\overline{z}=0$ and then reverse the order and you will get your answer (I multiplied both sides by 2 on the second equation.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We will first do it in reverse order so that we can go backwards and get the answer:
\begin{align*}
(\overline{z}-i)(z-2)&=-(z+i)(\overline{z}-2)\\
z\overline{z}-2\overline{z}-zi+2i&=-z\overline{z}-i\overline{z}+2z+2i\\
2z\overline{z}-2\overline{z}+i\overline{z}-zi-2z&=0\\
z\overline{z}-(1+\frac{1}{2}i)z+(-1+\frac{1}{2}i)\overline{z}&=0.
\end{align*}
And if we reverse it, we get:
\begin{align*}
z\overline{z}-(1+\frac{1}{2}i)z+(-1+\frac{1}{2}i)\overline{z}&=0\\
2z\overline{z}-2\overline{z}+i\overline{z}-zi-2z&=0\\
z\overline{z}-2\overline{z}-zi+2i&=-z\overline{z}-i\overline{z}+2z+2i\\
(\overline{z}-i)(z-2)&=-(z+i)(\overline{z}-2),
\end{align*}
which should be what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You already proved that
$$(z-1+\frac{1}{2}i)(\bar{z}-1-\frac{1}{2}i)-\frac{5}{4}=0$$
is equivalent to
$$z\bar{z}-(1+\frac{1}{2}i)z+(-1+\frac{1}{2}i)\bar{z}=0.$$
To prove that the latter is equivalent to
$$(\bar{z}-i)(z-2)=-(z+i)(\bar{z}-2),$$
simply expand this last equation.

Answer (score 0):

$f(z) + \overline{f(z)} = 0 \iff \operatorname{Re}\big(f(z)\big) = 0\,$, so the problem is equivalent to finding the preimage of the imaginary axis under the function $f(z)$ - or, in this case, verifying that it is the given circle.

$f(z)$ is a [Möbius transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_transformation) which maps [generalized circles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalised_circle) to generalized circles, and so is its inverse $f^{-1}(z) = \dfrac{2 z + i}{z - 1}$. The image of the imaginary axis under the transformation $f^{-1}(z)$ is the generalized circle through the $3$ points:

$$
\begin{align}
f^{-1}(0) &= -i
\\ f^{-1}(i) = \frac{3i}{i - 1} &= \frac{3}{2} (1 - i)
\\ f^{-1}(-i) = \frac{-i}{-i - 1} &= \frac{1}{2} ( 1 + i)
\end{align}
$$

Drawing the diagram in the complex plane makes it geometrically obvious that the $3$ points are the vertices of an isosceles right triangle, so its center is the midpoint of the hypotenuse $1 - \dfrac{1}{2} i$, and the radius is the distance from the center to either point, or $\dfrac{\sqrt{5}}{2}$.

[image]

Therefore the equation of the circle is $\,\left|z - 1 + \dfrac{1}{2} i\right|^2 = \dfrac{5}{4}\,$, which is indeed equivalent to the equation given in the problem.